# Download with file name defaulting to date-time of user event in Vaadin Flow app

Tags: download, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In my [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) web app (version 14 or later), I want to present to my user a link that will download a data file to them. The default name of the file to be downloaded should be determined at the moment the user initiates the download.

I am aware of the [`Anchor`](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-anchor) widget in Vaadin Flow. With an `Anchor`, the default name for the downloaded file will be the resource name given in the URL of the link. Unfortunately, that is determined when the page loads rather than later when the user clicks the link. So this approach fails to meet my need to label the download with the date-time captured at the moment the user initiates the download.

```
String when = Instant.now().toString().replace( "-" , "" ).replace( ":" , "" ); // Use "basic" version of standard ISO 8601 format for date-time.
StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource( "rows_" + when + ".txt" , ( ) -> this.makeContent() );
Anchor anchor = new Anchor( streamResource , "Download generated data" );
```

[image: screenshot of Anchor widget showing a link whose URL is frozen in time with an old date-time text value]

Perhaps the solution would be the use of a `Button` widget rather than an `Anchor`. Using a button for dynamically-created content is shown in the manual in the *Advanced Topics* > [*Dynamic Content*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content.html) page. Unfortunately, the example there loads a resource on the page rather than doing a download for the user.

➥ Can a `Button` in Vaadin Flow be used to initiate a download?

➥ Is there some other approach to initiating a download with a URL determined when the user initiates the download rather than when the page loads?

Answer (score 2):

> Can a Button in Vaadin Flow be used to initiate a download?

Sort of yes, but it requires some client side implementation. There is [File Download Wrapper](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/file-download-wrapper) add-on in Directory, which does this. With it is possible to wrap e.g. `Button`. However I think it will not solve problem of yours fully. I suspect that the setting the filename in click event wont apply (it comes too late). But I do think, that it would be possible to add filename provider callback feature to this add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this HACK that simulates a click on a dynamically added `Anchor` on client-side:

```java
    private void downloadWorkaround(Component anyComponent, int delay) {
        Anchor hiddenDownloadLink = new Anchor(createStreamResource(), "Workaround");
        hiddenDownloadLink.setId("ExportLinkWorkaround_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        hiddenDownloadLink.getElement().setAttribute("style", "display: none");
        var parent = anyComponent.getParent().orElseThrow();
        var parenthc = (HasComponents) parent;
        for (Component c : parent.getChildren().collect(Collectors.toList())) {
            if (c.getId().orElse("").startsWith("ExportLinkWorkaround_")) {
                // clean up old download link
                parenthc.remove(c);
            }
        }
        parenthc.add(hiddenDownloadLink);
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("setTimeout(function(){" + // delay as workaround for bug when dialog open before
                "document.getElementById('" + hiddenDownloadLink.getId().orElseThrow() + "').click();"
                + "}, " + delay + ");"
        );
    }
```

Call the method on button click event or something. The additional `delay` is required sometimes. For me the delay was necessary to start the download from a modal dialog OK button that also closed the dialog. But perhaps you don't even need that.

I had no luck with the file download wrapper add-on mentioned by Tatu for my specific use case: I wanted to show a dialog under some circumstances before providing the download to user.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question of [Clearing up Vaadin StreamResource after file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871381/clearing-up-vaadin-streamresource-after-file-download) (which is partly the same as the answer of Steffen Harbich here in this question) I came to this solution (Vaadin 23):

Just provide a normal button with a normal clickHandler.

In the clickHandler you determine the file name, create a local StreamResource, add it to an invisible UI element and trigger a click event on this element.

Clickhandler:

```
private void doOnDownloadBtnClicked( Event e )
{
    String filename = createFileName(); // implementation left to you
    downloadFile( filename, this::inputStreamProvider );
}
```

InputStream provider:

```
private InputStream inputStreamProvider()
{
    ....
}
```

File download (may be extracted to an Utility class):

```
private final StreamResourceRegistry myStreamResourceRegistry;

private void downloadFile( String aFileName, InputStreamFactory aInputStreamFactory )
{
    myStreamResourceRegistry = new StreamResourceRegistry(VaadinSession.getCurrent());
    var executor = new DownloadExecutor( aInputStreamFactory );

    var sr = new StreamResource( aFileName, executor );
    StreamRegistration reg = myStreamResourceRegistry.registerResource( sr );
    executor.myRegistration = reg;

    var hiddenDownloadLink = new Anchor(sr, "Hidden");
    var hiddenDownloadLinkId =
            StringUtils.replaceChars( "DownloadLinkWorkaroundId-" + new SecureRandom().nextLong(),
                                      '-',
                                      '_' ) ;
    hiddenDownloadLink.setId( hiddenDownloadLinkId);
    var hiddenElement = hiddenDownloadLink.getElement();
    executor.myHiddenElement = hiddenElement;
    hiddenElement.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
    var uiParent = UI.getCurrent().getElement();
    executor.myParentElement = uiParent;
    uiParent.appendChild(hiddenElement);
    LOG.debug( "Going to simulate click event" );
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("$0.click();", hiddenElement );
}

/**
 * Wrapper for the given InputStreamFactory.
 * <p>
 * It is needed to let Vaadin first give a chance to call the InputStream provider, before the
 * temporary added hidden anchor is removed and the StreamRegistration is unregistered.
 */
private static final class DownloadExecutor implements InputStreamFactory
{
    private InputStreamFactory myInputStreamFactory;
    private StreamRegistration myRegistration;
    private Element myHiddenElement;
    private Element myParentElement;

    private DownloadExecutor( InputStreamFactory aInputStreamFactory )
    {
        super();
        myInputStreamFactory = aInputStreamFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream createInputStream()
    {
        var result = myInputStreamFactory.createInputStream();
        myParentElement.removeChild( myHiddenElement );
        myRegistration.unregister();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Note: If the above fileDownload is extracted to an own helper class (e.g. a spring bean with @SessionScope), the initialization of myStreamResourceRegistry should be done in the constructor of the bean.